# How Does Switching To A Enchanted Sword Whilst Arrow Is Shot Effect The Entity Shot

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When switching to a looting sword when throwing a splash potion of harming to kill mobs will result in the looting taking effect, does this apply as well to a bow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes switching to a Looting Sword will have the effect applied when a arrow kills a mob.

I killed 10 skeletons in each test and the results are:

Diamond Sword:
[image]

Diamond Sword (Looting X):
[image]

Bow:
[image]

Bow (Switching to Looting X Sword):
[image]

Switching Bows when the arrow is shot won't effect the Arrow and switching to a knock back sword won't effect the arrow.